# I want to split path to working directory in perl script

Tags: perl

```
#!/applications/dte/perl5/bin/perl -w    
use File::Basename;    
use strict;    

my $DTE_WORK_DIR = dirname($0);    
print "DTE $DTE_WORK_DIR\n";    
my $DTE_WORKING_DIR = split ('/\//', $DTE_WORK_DIR);    
print "WORKDIR = $DTE_WORKING_DIR\n";
```

run it as /path/to/dir/filename.pl
Use of implicit split to @_ is deprecated at /applications/dte/sh/oleg.pl line 15.
DTE /path/to/dir
workdir=1

Comment: Your statement `my $var = split (/\//, $fulpath)` will set `$var` to 4. Why don't you read the documentation before getting the whole world involved in fixing your code?

Comment: What is the error message? Don't you think that a `/` inside regex delimiters of `/` might need to be escaped somehow?

Comment: I read and that is what I found

Comment: Huh? You read *what* and found *what*?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: right now I put line my $var = split ('///', $fullpath). No error, but doesn't do anything

Comment: Maybe you want `dirname()` from [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) since you can't be bothered to read the docs for `split()`?

Comment: Use of implicit split to @_ is deprecated at /applications/dte/sh/oleg.pl line 15.

Comment: @Matt, I am using dirname, but it gives me full path. I need only first two

Comment: Your question says you did `my $var = split (/\//, $fulpath)` and your comment says `my $var = split ('/\//', $fullpath)`. Which is it? They're totally different.

Comment: Wait... you're using `dirname()` now?

Comment: I am using dirname to get path without filename and get /path/to/dir. I want to split by last slash and get /path/to

Comment: $fullpath = dirname, $0 is my syntax, and it gives me the full path. I don't need full path, I need it without last sl;ash and dir

Comment: That's not what your question says! Please, just stop for a second. [...] Ok, now [edit] your question to include the **actual** code you're having trouble with, *along with* any error messages you've received. See: [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: check please now my post and help.

Comment: Why don't you just replace the `split()` with `dirname($DTE_WORK_DIR)`?

Comment: @osamuyl Borodin told you in the very first comment what the problem is.  The `split` returns a _list_. You are assigning to a _scalar_ (a single value), so what is Perl to do? IT will work out the _length of the list_ (number of elements) and assign that.  That's why you get a number from it (and I don't see why it's "1").  So, do `my @dirs = split ...` and `@dirs` will have all directories from the path.

Comment: Perfectly works, But I still want to get how the split function works. Can you let me know or at least link to correct documentation?

Comment: @osamuyl  Oh ... I thought you would know how to find docs.  Here, this is the page for [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).  More importantly, use [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/) to find _a lot_ of docs, practically everything you need. Look at the bars at the left (for example, go to tutorials), use the search box.  Finally, most questions that come up while you are learning a language have been answered. So, search for it, either directly here or in Google (and go to links to SO, I recommend).  Spend a few minutes searching and you'll then have all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have found your question very difficult to understand - but this is my take - you want to take a directory like

```
/this/is/some/kind/of/path/to/nowhere
```

This you want to break it apart and rebuild it

Try doing something like this - to build to path with the first two directories

```
(@directoryNames)=split(/\//, $someDirectory);
$newDirectory=$directoryName[0]."\/".$directoryName[0];
```

You could probably also play around with shift / unshift / pop etc.